# List Column autoincrementing Identifier

Tags: list, column, calculated-column

I want to create sequential ID for transactions under a specific account. So, lets say I have an account XYZ. The first transaction ID should be XYZ-1. The second XYZ-2 and so on.

I have a two lists. One I use to log all accounts. The second list is the one I use to log all transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below
 Store last increment number somewhere else in other list, read this number and create unique number.updated this number every time a new transaction item is created.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through by following below methods :

1.A Workflow can be attached to that list and once the item is created workflow can be triggered and the calculations based on the ID column can be acheived here

2.An item added event reciever can be added to this list and the calculations based on the ID field can be achieved through this

In Calculated Columns we cant use ID field as it doesn't behave as expected..

Answer (score 0):

I would also consider custom IIDProvider and using Document ID feature, if custom implementation is not an issue:

"You can use custom providers to assign document IDs to items. In some organizations, specific item metadata drives how IDs are assigned. This helps ensure that the ID conveys information about the item.

SharePoint Server 2010 supports using custom code plug-ins to provision document IDs. You can author your own custom providers by implementing a class that derives from the IIDProvider interface and then deploying and registering that provider in each site collection. After a custom provider is registered, the document ID service uses the custom provider instead of the default provider."

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559302.aspx)